# Show / Hide Multiple divs with out using a numerical value

Tags: jquery, html

Okay so the code shown here at http://jsfiddle.net/PayBt/ works perfectly but I have one problem. My values CAN'T be numbers which kills the code.

HTML:

```
<select id="additional" name="additional" value="{{course}}">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="apatient6">6</option>
</select>
        <div id="workshop1" class="formbox">stuff</div>
        <div id="workshop2" class="formbox">stuff</div>
        <div id="workshop3" class="formbox">stuff</div>
        <div id="workshop4" class="formbox">stuff</div>
```

JS.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.formbox').hide();
$('#additional').change(function () {
    $('.formbox').hide();
    for (i = 1; i <= $(this).val(); i++) {
        $('#workshop' + i).show();
    }
});
});
```

The options I see are make it     $('#workshop' + val).show(); instead of $('#workshop' + i).show();. Or find a way to call the div's by the selectors ID's.

Basically how to show / hide multiple divs with out using numerical values?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is working perfectly fine for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom data attribute like `data-value` like this -

Html :  (*same for other options*)

```
<option data-value='6' value="apatient6">6</option>
```

Js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.formbox').hide();
    $('#additional').change(function () {
        $('.formbox').hide();
        for (i = 1; i <= parseInt($('option:selected',this).data('value')); i++) {
            $('#workshop' + i).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo  `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/PayBt/8/

Comment: Thank you. I attempted to do a data-value but I apparently don't know enough javascript yet. This works perfectly thank you very much! Both of the above work, though this is the one that works best with my situation hence why I deemed it the correct answer, Antila thank you for proving a quality answer as well!

Comment: @JohnathonMathews Glad, it helped you ! Anyway, you can learn more about `.data()` here `-->` http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the selectedIndex from the DOM-element, which is what it sounds like. The index of the selected item. Then you can use the :lt() selector in jQuery to grab all elements with a lower index:

```
$('#additional').change(function () {
    $('.formbox').hide();
    var selectedIndex = $('#additional').get(0).selectedIndex;
    $('.formbox:lt(' + selectedIndex + ')').show();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/PayBt/10/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are interested in the selected index of the element, a simple tweak to your existing could is sufficient!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.formbox').hide();
    $('#additional').change(function () {
        $('.formbox').hide();
        //jquery api magic
        iters = $("#additional").get(0).selectedIndex;
        for (i = 1; i <= iters; i++) {
            $('#workshop' + i).show();
        }
    });
});
```